# trying to get property of a non object in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, isset

I am using Laravel 4 and I am trying to pass information if the user IS logged in. If the user is not logged in I want to display something else in plain text

**BookController**

```
public function showIndex() { 

    $user_information = UsersInformation::find(Auth::user()->id);

    return View::make('book.index', array('pageTitle' => 'Book your appointment',  'user_information' => $user_information));
}
```

I tried adding isset() right above the $user_information variable but got this error message

```
Cannot use isset() on the result of a function call 
   (you can use "null !== func()" instead)
```

**Index.blade.php**

```
        @if (isset($user_information->first_name))
           <p> You already have the 1 step complete let's move on to the second step!</p>
        @else
           <p>first step. let's create a login name and let's get to know you better</p>
        @endif
```

added the isset here for the first name because if they access their account they must provide a first name.

I attempted to add the isset as follows:

```
             if (isset(UsersInformation::find(Auth::user()->id))) {
                $user_information = UsersInformation::find(Auth::user()->id);
             }
```

I of course tried using the recommended syntax but then once again got the 'Trying to get property of a non object' error

Comment: Show us the actual code where you use `isset()`, and any other relavant code as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check if the user is logged in first:

```
public function showIndex() { 

    if (Auth::check())
    {
        $user_information = UsersInformation::find(Auth::user()->id);
    }
    else
    {
        $user_information = false;
    }

    return View::make('book.index', array('pageTitle' => 'Book your appointment',  'user_information' => $user_information));
}
```

And then you just:

```
@if ($user_information and $user_information->first_name)
   <p> You already have the 1 step complete let's move on to the second step!</p>
@else
   <p>first step. let's create a login name and let's get to know you better</p>
@endif
```